# Cant change the row source of a bounded combo box in Ms-access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I am trying to fill up the row source of a bounded combo box  programmatically  in Ms-Access. However, it does not show any of the numbers when I view the form.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.cmbErrorType.RowSourceType = "Value List"
    Me.cmbErrorType.RowSource = "1;2;3;4;5;6"
End Sub
```

When the form opens, I click on combo box, and it shows nothing in the drop down menu.

As far as I know, row source is used to build up the items in the combo box than why is this happening ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Tried your code, works for me just fine.

Comment: Did you try with bounded combo boxes ?

Comment: Yes, bound the combo to a table, then used your code on Form open, it changed to the `Value List` with the numbers 1-6 fine.

Comment: In your table design, in the lookup, is the display control for that particular field a text box or a combo box?

Comment: Turns out it works fine if I make that particular field a text box. But it does not work if its a combo box. I don't understand why.

Comment: Mine was set to textbox

Comment: try making it a combo box and run the form again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120836/discussion-between-haris-ghauri-and-random-answer-guy).

Comment: What is the data type of your field? How many columns do you have set in your cmbBox - and have you set any of the column widths = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand the situation, you are using the lookup property of a field in a table with display control as combo box.

[image]

If you bound the field with `Display Control` as `Combo Box` to a   `Form.ComboBox`, it somehow overrides the `rowsource` property when you try to show the drop down list. To show the list, you either need to change the display control in your `Field Properties`

> [Database].TableDefs("TableName").Fields("Field").Properties("DisplayControl") = acTextBox

or

> Keep the DisplayControl property to textbox  when designing the table in the first place.

or change  the Field `Row`Source` property

> [Database].TableDefs("TableName").Fields("Field").Properties("RowSource") = "1;2;3;4;5;6"

Comment: Your answer makes no sense - do you have code that you can show that actually works - this will not compile let alone be understood

Comment: your right, i am actually tyring to add comments from the original post comments thread but it won't allow me because of characters limit. Anyways, i updated the answer to make it clearer about the case.